# New to java, panels not switched in my cardlayout

Tags: java, swing, cardlayout

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong please?

I have..

```
    JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();

    comboBox.addItem("Factor 1");
    comboBox.addItem("Factor 2");
    comboBox.addItem("Factor 3");

    comboBox.setSelectedIndex(-1);

    studyPlanController.setFactors(comboBox);
    MyItemListener itemListener = new MyItemListener();

    comboBox.addItemListener(itemListener);
    itemListener.setFactors(cardFactors);
```

and..

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MyItemListener implements ItemListener {
    JPanel factors;

    public void setFactors(JPanel factors) {
        this.factors = factors;
    }

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) (factors.getLayout());
        cl.show(factors, (String) e.getItem());
    }

}
```

When a breakpoint is placed in itemStateChanged(), and the combox is changed, then the breakpoint is hit, however the cardlayout remains uneffected.

Comment: something wrong in the code you are not showing ;-) Time for an SSCCE. BTW: in your itemListener you probably only want to change the card on a item_selected event, not on an item_deselected

Comment: why 2nd. time http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594306/overlap-jpanels-with-windowbuilder-for-eclipse , follows example from this tutorial

Comment: mKorbel - it's a differnet question.

Comment: Twice you've been given the link to the Swing tutorial which contains a working example. So compare your code with the working tutorial example to see what is different. Or start with the working code and then change each panel to be your custom panel. The code you posted in incomplete so we can't help without guessing.

Comment: camickr - I have been using the swing tutorial as a guide. When your new to a language, it's often difficult to perfectly form your questions. However, I do appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html

Please check that you are adding the panels to card layout with same name as that shows up in the combobox. There might be mismatch in the names.

Comment: You were right! thanks, I was passing the string constant name of the panel to the card layout in quotes. doh