# Program with split screen, how can I change the content [Java]

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

[image: sketch]

I had just a few class of java on college, but I want to do a thing that I don't know how.

Is basically a window with a SplitPane, on **Left side** I have a menu made with toggle buttons, and on the **Right side** I need to change the content based on each button.

- Theres any way to design the **ViewA** and **ViewB** on separated `JFrame Form` and load then inside my `Right Side` when I click on menu items?
- Another idea is, put the ViewA and ViewB put a `JTabbedPane` on the **Right Side**, and hide the Tabs. So there's any way to hide the tabs?

I have none experience developing in java, any problem about this concept (difficult, loading time, memory, maintenance), If you guy know a better way to to this, I just don't want a lot of windows popping up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A really simply way would be to simply have a set of `jPanels` in the right side, with only one ever set to `Visible`.

Basically, for each toggle on the left side, you will have an Event Listener that does this:

```
 private void toggle1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                        

jPanel1.setVisible(false); 
jPanel2.setVisible(false);
jPanel3.setVisible(true);
}
```

Simply changing the true value depending on the individual toggle.

In Netbeans, if using the GUI editor, you can simply double click the toggle button to generate the listener and appropriate method, then fill in the code for it.

Comment: I thought this too but, I can't overlap panels. If I change my layout to null I can overlap but my panels stop resizing with the parent window. If you know how to do this please tell me how.

Comment: @Vitimtk please see my answer here.  This is how I did it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594306/overlap-jpanels-with-windowbuilder-for-eclipse/8594867#8594867

Comment: I put my panels `ViewA` and `ViewB` inside the panel `ContentArea` and set the layout of the `ContentArea` as "CardLayout", and used setVisible to switch views. Thanks a lot